# Multirow in tabularx?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

Can we use multirow in tabularx?
It seemed not working and recognized:

```
\multirow{2}{*}{95\% Confidence
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small} % for bold in table using \small
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccc}
    \toprule
    & &  & \thead{\small {\textbf{Statistic}}}& \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Error}}} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Difference} & Mean
    & & 44.20000 & 4.54068  \\
\cline{2-5}
    & \multirow{2}{*}{95\% Confidence Interval for Mean} & Lower Bound & 33.9283 & \\
\cline{3-5}
    & & Upper Bound & \54.4717 \\
\cline{2-5}
    & Kurtosis & & -1.000 & 1.334 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Outcome:

[image]

I actually want something like below:

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question only with appropriate tags. I notice that a lot of your questions have been tagged with `biblatex` even though they were about tables and  have nothing to to with `biblatex`. (Ironically, one of your questions that was about `biblatex` was not tagged with `biblatex` initially.) Appropriate tagging makes it easier for people to find your question and avoids confusions. I'm only mentioning this now since I noticed that this became a pattern and people always had to re-tag your questions that were otherwise tagged quite well.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. I was thinking this writing is `biblatex`. I will take note it next time.

Comment: I see. `biblatex` (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is a bibliography and citation package that has usually nothing to do with tables. One sign that this question is not about `biblatex` is that your MWE does not load the package at all (there is no `\usepackage{biblatex}` or `\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}`).

Comment: @moewe, Thanks. Noted. In my MWE, i used `\usepackage{booktabs}`. Is that mean i can tag `booktabs`? Is this correct way?

Comment: More or less, it is not always easy to decide on tags and for package tags like `booktabs` or `biblatex` the fact that you use the package is more of a necessary condition rather than a sufficient condition to use the tag. In this case I would guess that `booktabs` is not actually that relevant to the problem at hand and would not tag the question with `booktabs`, but I may well be wrong. The important tags are certainly `multirow` and `tables` and possibly to a lesser extent `tabularx`.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. You don't need to get everything "right" on a first attempt: Sometimes it only transpires what is really relevant once the answer is known. And people here are well aware that tagging is an art and not always easy. If one knows what `biblatex` does it is fairly clear from the MWE that it is not involved and hence the tag not helpful. Since `biblatex` popped up a lot in your question tags (and almost always was not relevant) I thought it would be better to mention it than silently correcting it for all future questions.

Comment: As your MWE gives you several error messages such as the following: `! Undefined control sequence. <inserted text> ...68 \\ \cline {2-5} & \multirow{2}{*}{95\% [...]`, please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: I would love to use both \multirow{2}{*}{text} and \multirow{3}{*}{xxx} in a tabularx. Which of the answers would work best for me?

Answer (score 5):

You can 1) if you load `multirow` and 2) use the `=` key, since you're in a fixed width column. 
I took the liberty to use the `S` column type for the last two columns, to have an alignment of the numbers on the decimal dot, and set the font for the column heads instead of hard coding each in the table. Also, I replaced the `\cline`s with `\cmidrule` s to add some padding around the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small} % for bold in table using \small
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XcS[table-format=-1.5]S[table-format=1.5]}
    \toprule
    & & & {\thead{Statistic}}& {\thead{Std. Error}} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Difference} & Mean
    & & 44.20000 & 4.54068 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & \multirow{2}{=}{95\% Confidence Interval for Mean} & Lower Bound & 33.9283 & \\
\cmidrule{3-5}
    & & Upper Bound & \ 54.4717 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Kurtosis & & -1.000 & 1.334 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, I think that the figures should be `normalised` (padded with zeros) to have the same number of decimals. This was the recommendation in two books regarding typography which I have read the last month (one Norwegian, one American). However, if you have text after the last decimal (parenthesis, footnotemark) you should align at the decimal point.

Comment: @Sveinung: this is  a sensible point of view, except perhaps for the kurtosis, which seems to have a very different order of magnitude.

Comment: Of cause, if adding zeros changes the meaning, you should not add them. But how can -1.000 00 be different from -1.000? (Stupid lawyer question :) )

Comment: The difference lies  in the number of significant figures it implies.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for enlighten me.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use a `\multirow` directive. Instead, I would place the cell contents into a bespoke `tabular` environment, as is done in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, % for 'tabularx' env.
            ragged2e, % for \RaggedRight macro
            booktabs, % for \toprule, \midrule, etc
            siunitx,  % for 'S' column type
            amsmath}  % for [b] option of \smash command
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}L@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
%%\centering % not needed
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} l L l 
    S[table-format=-1.5] 
    S[table-format= 1.5] @{}}
\toprule
& & & {Statistic} & {Std.\ Error} \\
\midrule
Difference & Mean & & 44.20000 & 4.54068  \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& \mytab{95\% Confidence Interval for Mean} & Lower Bound & 33.9283 & \\
\cmidrule(l){3-5}
& & Upper Bound & 54.4717 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& Kurtosis & & -1.000 & 1.334 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you typeset a `calstable` using the package [cals](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/), spanning cells horizontally and vertically centre them, is easy.

[image]

```
\documentclass[british, DIV=12, captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cals, url}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{luximono}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage[letterspace=100,%
                babel=true,%
                tracking=true,%
                kerning=true]%
        {microtype}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop}
\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\addtokomafont{caption}{\sffamily\bfseries\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{A caption}
\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/6\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 5

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.6pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.6pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\lp{\ifdim\cals@paddingL=0.0pt\relax    % Left padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}\fi}

\def\rp{\ifdim\cals@paddingR=0.0pt\relax    % Right padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}

% R1H1
\thead{\bfseries%
\brow
    \lp\cell{}\lp
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \alignR\cell{\vfil Statistics}
    \rp\alignR\cell{\vfil Std. Error}\rp
\erow
\mdseries%
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R2B1
\brow
    \lp\bb\alignL\cell{Difference}\lp
    \bb\alignL\cell{Mean}
    \cell{}
     \alignR\cell{44.200\,00}
    \rp\alignR\cell{4.540\,68}\rp\bb
\erow
%R3B2
\brow
    \lp\cell{}\lp
    \nc{lrt}
    \bb\alignL\cell{Lower Bound}
    \alignR\cell{33.928\,30}
    \rp\cell{}\rp\bb
\erow
%R4B3
\brow
    \lp\cell{}\lp
    \bb\nc{lrb}\alignL\sc{\vfil 95\% Confidence\\ Interval for Mean}
    \alignL\cell{Upper Bound}
    \alignR\cell{54.471\,70}
    \rp\cell{}\rp
\erow
%R5B4
\brow
    \lp\cell{}\lp
    \alignL\cell{Kurtosis}
    \cell{}
    \alignR\cell{-1.000\hspace*{0.9em}}
    \rp\alignR\cell{1.334\hspace*{0.9em}}\rp
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had tried `\input{glyphtounicode}` But there is an error. I am using Overleaf. It said `LaTex Error: File MinionPro.sty``

Comment: @aan Sorry for not cleaning up the MWE. Replace `\usepackage[footnotefigures]{MinionPro}` with `\usepackage{lmodern}` and delete the two next lines, i.e. `\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1`. Also package `url`, `luximono` and `xcolor` is unnecessary.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, working well now. Thanks